# How can I store the record into string array from Enumerable model list

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

I am trying to store the list of record into a string array as given format as given. I have given the format of the layout as given with data need to be stored in string array myData
[string Array Format link](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Drop-Down-Combo-Tree.html)

```
   var myData = [
       {
         id: 1,
         title: 'Depot 1 ',
       subs: [
           {
             id: 1.1,
             title: 'Depot 1.Admin'
           }, 
       {
             id: 1.2,
             title: 'Depot 1.Accounts'
           },  
         ]
       }, 
      {
         id: 2,
         title: 'Depot 2',
         subs: [
           {
             id: 2.1,
             title: 'Depot 2.Admin'
           }, {
             id: 2.2,
             title: 'Depot 2.Accounts'
           }, {
             id: 2.3,
             title: 'Depot 2.Sales'
           }
         ]
       }
   ];
```

for this purpose I have three model

```
   public class Depot
   {
       public  int Id { get; set; }
       public string  DepoName { get; set; }
   }
   public class Department
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string  DepartmentName { get; set; }
   }
   public class DepotDepartmentLink
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public int DepotId { get; set; }
       public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
       public Depot Depot { get; set; }
       public Department Department { get; set; }
   }
```

```
Depot contains the record  
Id =1 , Depotname = Depot 1  
Id =2 , Depotname = Depot 2

Department contains the record  
Id =1 , Departmentname = Admin  
Id =2 , Departmentname = Accounts  
Id =3 , Departmentname = Sales
Departmentlink contains
Depotid = 1 DepartmentId = 1
Depotid = 1 DepartmentId = 2
Depotid = 2 DepartmentId = 1
Depotid = 2 DepartmentId = 2
Depotid = 2 DepartmentId = 3
```

in  Repository class

```
   public IEnumerable<DepotDepartmentLink> GetAllDepotDepartmentLink()
   {         
      return _db.DepotDepartmentLink.Include(m => m.Depot).Include(m=>m.Department);
   }
```

In controller I am trying to bring the data  the result into array myData as given format above. Please help

```
   public IActionResult Index()
   {    
       IEnumerable<DepotDepartmentLink> depotdepartment = _depotDepartmentLinkRepo.GetAllDepotDepartmentLink();
       string myData = "[]";
      
       myData = "[" + string.Join(",",depotdepartment.Select(l => l.DepotId + "." + l.DepartmentId).ToArray());    
       return View();
   }
```

Comment: Did you try using JSON serialization?

Comment: whether the object you want display in view or something else , to convert to json sting array have toserialise add reference newtonsoft and like  string jstr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(depotdepartment, Formatting.Indented);

Comment: Please can you guide me from my example how can I convert into json string array

Comment: Chetan , I tried as you advised but not working. Because the string array should be passed in the same format as I attached  above

Comment: And `DepotDepartmentLink` contains the ...?

Comment: I have given the depotdepartmentlink data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple grouping of data. It is done elementary using LINQ.
Then we get json using any serializer.

```
var result = depotdepartment
    .GroupBy(dd => new { dd.DepotId, dd.Depot.DepoName })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        id = g.Key.DepotId,
        title = g.Key.DepoName,
        subs = g.Select(dd => new
        {
            id = dd.DepotId + "." + dd.DepartmentId,
            title = dd.Depot.DepoName + "." + dd.Department.DepartmentName
        })
    });

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Formatting.Indented);
```